# Veeam replica timeout

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, veeam

I'm encountering an issue during a Veeam replication job, specifically a "Preparing replica VM Error." The error message indicates: "A connection attempt failed because the remote site did not respond after a certain period of time, or the established connection was incorrect because the connected host did not respond."

To temporarily resolve this problem, I've been rebooting the ESXi host, which gets rid of the error and allows me to connect and restart veeam replica jobs to ESXi without any issues. However, this problem reoccurs approximately every 3-4 days, and I'm faced with the same error.

Moreover, when this issue occurs, I'm unable to retrieve any information from the ESXi host via ssh using various commands such as:

```
esxcli system hostname get
esxcli system stats installtime get
esxcli software vib list
esxcli storage vmfs extent list
esxcli storage filesystem list
esxcli esxcli command list
esxcli storage
```

None of the above commands provide a response. However, I can still log in to the ESXi server through the web interface, but it appears to be unresponsive in some sections.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any insights on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: With virtually no information the only advice can be contact the Veeam support. You bought it, use it.